# why fetch_assoc work on while?

Tags: php

#1 code

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc());
while ($row) {
// code here
}
```

#2 code

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc());) {
// code here
}
```

Why #1 code and #2 code give different result?

Comment: Unless you modify `$row` in the loop, the first one is an infinite loop over the first record of the result.

Comment: You need to add more of the `//code here` part as @David suggests. This example is not complete, unless you are asking why example #1 results in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because in #1 you execute `fetch_assoc()` only once, while in #2 you execute it  on every loop iteration.

In other words, in #2 `fetch_assoc()` will keep on returning rows as long as there are rows available in the result set. #1 will enter an infinite loop if there is at least one row available.

Comment: At first I thought that `while` work on array, because `var_dump($result->fetch_assoc())` return array